# Unexpected Python output Chmod Command Line

Tags: python, zsh

Thank you in advance for the feedback!

I have a simple hello.py file which I am exploring in the Command Line.

When I run the following command:

```
python hello.py
```

I get an expected output:

```
Hello World
```

But when I run it with the Execute Bit command

```
chmod +x hello.py
./hello.py
```

I get the following output:

```
('Hello', 'World')
```

I do not get why the second output is enclosed in parentheses and displayed as separately quoted strings. My python version is Python 3.8.5. If it matters my shell is zsh.

Here is the hello.py file:

```
import sys

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
def main():
  # Get the name from the command line, using 'World' as a fallback.
  if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    name = sys.argv[1]
  else:
    name = 'World'
  print ('Hello', name)

# This is the standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Start your script with a proper shebang along lines of `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: When you run `python hello.py` you are most likely running a python 3.X version. You can check this by executing: `python --version`. When you run it as an executable, a python 2.X version is running your code and hence leads to the tuple. As @Mark Setchell is saying, you need to provide the correct path in your shebang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to be able to run the script with just its name, the file needs to have a valid shebang line. You are not showing yours, but apparently your script has one, or else the shell would attempt to run it as a shell script.  Unfortunately, your shebang is pointing to Python 2, where you would want it to point to Python 3.

On many Linux systems, `#!/usr/bin/python` (or the morally equivalent but somewhat more flexible `#!/usr/bin/env python`) will run Python 2, whereas `#!/usr/bin/python3` (or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`) will run Python 3.

Whether `python` on the command line runs Python 3 is by and large irrelevant; this is probably an interactive alias set up by your shell, but it *only* works interactively.